# MySQL: Using JOIN to get parent row with the most recent child row only

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

- News (`news` alias `tn`)
- News category (`news_cat` alias `tc`)
- News pictures (`news_pic` alias `tp`)

I need to get the most recent news, each one with their category and only the first picture for that specific post, using `o` as the order field.

This is my current sql query:

```
SELECT
tn.date_news AS date_news,
tn.title AS title,
tn.text AS text,
tn.url AS url,
tc.name AS cat,
tp.file AS file
FROM news AS tn
JOIN news_cat AS tc ON tc.id_cat = tn.id_cat
JOIN (
    SELECT file FROM news_pic WHERE news_pic.id_news = tn.id_news ORDER BY temp.o LIMIT 1
) AS tp ON tp.id_news = tn.id_news
WHERE
tn.flg_featured = 1
ORDER BY tc.date_news DESC LIMIT 6
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tn.id_news' in 'where clause'
```

[This is the sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ccc34/8) with the tables' structure and some example data. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You have missing column tn.id_news in select. Try to add tn.id_news in select

Comment: @YogeshPatel Thanks, but that didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `greatest-n-per-group` problem; you need to find the minimum value of `o` for each value of `id_news` and then `JOIN` `news_pic` to itself on the `o` value matching that minimum value to get the first picture. Note that you have a couple of other errors (`tc.flg_featured` should be `tn.flg_featured` and `tc.date_news` should be `tn.date_news`). This should give you the results you want:

```
SELECT
  tn.date_news AS date_news,
  tn.title AS title,
  tn.text AS text,
  tn.url AS url,
  tc.name AS cat,
  tp.file AS file
FROM news AS tn
JOIN news_cat AS tc ON tc.id_cat = tn.id_cat
JOIN news_pic tp ON tp.id_news = tn.id_news
JOIN (
  SELECT id_news, MIN(o) AS o
  FROM news_pic
  GROUP BY id_news
) AS tpm ON tpm.id_news = tn.id_news AND tpm.o = tp.o
WHERE tn.flg_featured = 1
ORDER BY tn.date_news DESC
LIMIT 6
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/990741/3)

Comment: Thanks! Actually it should be MIN(o) since this is the order (first order is 1), but this solved the problem.

Comment: @AndresSK ah yes - I'm so used to these being `greatest` rather than `least`. :) I've updated the answer.